# Why ref object existed before assign it to target in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried `Ref and forwarding-refs` in Reactjs to keep a reference to a DOM or React Component. I did not understand why the `ref object` in which created kept correct target reference **before** target component was rendered or mounted.
I have the [codesandbox right here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-field-pudiv?file=/src/FancyButtonHOC.js) to present my question more details. Here is the screenshot
[image]

As what you see, Ref object keep a correct reference to the target (in this case is FancyButton Component) even the render and ComponentDidMount method of target have not yet fired.
Could someone possibly help me to understand about this more. Thanks.

Comment: You have class inside a functional component. Are you sure that it`s working correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because console keep reference to current value to object (so you get value of object after rendering). If you will change your code to

```
console.log(JSON.stringif(ref))
```

Then you will get this:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8fWn.png)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I would like to add my thoughts about this like this. V8 engine in Chrome evaluated console.log command with the ref's current property is null but have not printed yet in the Console Tab of Developer tool. After that (after the rendering phase in Event-loop of V8), the current property of ref object will be updated with correct references? Please correct me if i wrong.

Comment: I think it is print out like you say after the rendering phase. but even if is rendered in console and after eg. 5 second the value will change, then console view will update to current one. This is not 'frozen', console keep reference to "live" object.

Comment: Do you have any link mention about how console view in devtool work, in relation to Event-loop @Robert? I love to understand kind of these things :).

Answer (score 1):

You are console logging in quite a few wrong places, namely the `console.log("render of Fancybutton");` in the render method of `FancyButton` and in the function body of `forwardRef` of the `FancyHOC`. The render method should be a pure function without side-effect. Console logging is considered a side-effect.

Study this react component lifecycle diagram:

[image]

Notice where the render function resides. It resides in the "Render Phase" of the render cycle. Notice also that it "May be paused, aborted or restarted by React." This means they are called ***before*** anything in the "Commit Phase".

Notice now as well that the other component lifecycle methods, specifically `componentDidMount` and its functional component coutnerpart `useEffect` with empty dependency array are all called *after* the component has rendered (committed to DOM) at least once.

Fix the logging in the incorrect places:

`FancyButtonHOC`

Move the logs into `componentDidUpdate` and `useEffect` hook.

```
function createFancyButtonHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  class FancyHOC extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const { forwardRef, ...rest } = this.props;
      return <WrappedComponent ref={forwardRef} {...rest} />;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("FancyHOC mounted");
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
      console.log("render of HOC: ", this.props.forwardRef);
    }
  }

  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log("forwardRef callback:  ", ref);
    });
    return <FancyHOC forwardRef={ref} {...props} />;
  });
}
```

In `FancyButton` if you leave the console log in the render method it will simply log any time react is invoking the render method for DOM diffing purposes, not actually when it is rendered *to the DOM* during the commit phase. Move it to `componentDidUpdate`.

```
export default class FancyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("fancy button mounted");
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("render of Fancybutton");
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log("button click");
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>;
  }
}
```

New console log output

```
render of HOC: {current: FancyButton}
fancy button mounted 
FancyHOC mounted 
forwardRef callback: {current: FancyButton}
```

[image]

[image: Edit zealous-jackson-6gvo0]

Comment: thank you for your very details answer. It help me understand more about how Reactjs work